# Сетка bootstrap и мои костыли

Tags: bootstrap

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста новичку, является ли нормальным использование блока с классом .container внутри блока .container-fluid? Или это страшный костыль? Для чего нужно - к примеру navbar нужен фиксированной ширины, потом пару блоков full-width, потом снова блок фиксированной ширины.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не нужно делать все блоки в одном `.container`, делайте блок за блоком и для каждого используйте нужный либо `.container`, либо `.container-fluid` и тогда этот вопрос отпадет.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="menu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      Секция 1
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      Секция 2
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      Секция 3
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

<!-- И т. д. -->
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я блоки оборачивал в container/container-fluid... В этом и косяк.

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите пожалуйста новичку, является ли нормальным использование
>   блока с классом .container внутри блока .container-fluid?

Это не нормально, должен быть один container. Для чего вам два контейнера?
.container - имеет ширину фикс (1170 пикселей.)
Если вы хотите, чтобы контент сайта был растянут на ширину вашего экрана (например более 1170 пикс), используйте уже тогда:
.container-fluid - это ширина 100%